# Libgdx: how to detect if an enemy was touched?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I want to add to the score of my game +1 when an enemy was touched, I tried two methods `addListener` and `touchDown` but not worked for me or I didn't use them right.

How can I do that my (enemy object is linked to an userData and Actor classes, I regroup many different sizes for my enemy in an enum class also those enemies move from the top of the screen to bot. How to detect if an enemy was touched?

```
public class GameStage extends Stage {
    // This will be our viewport measurements while working with the debug renderer
    private static final int VIEWPORT_WIDTH = 13;
    private static final int VIEWPORT_HEIGHT = 20;

    private World world;
    private Ground ground;
    private Enemy enemy;
    private final float TIME_STEP = 1 / 300f;
    private float accumulator = 0f;
    private Rectangle bounds;
    private Vector3 touchPoint = new Vector3();;
    private int score;
    private String yourScoreName;
    BitmapFont yourBitmapFontName;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private Box2DDebugRenderer renderer;

    public GameStage() {
        world = WorldUtils.createWorld();
        renderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        score = 0;
        yourScoreName = "score: 0";
        yourBitmapFontName = new BitmapFont();
        setUpWorld();
        setUpCamera();
    }

    public void setUpWorld(){
        world = WorldUtils.createWorld();
        setUpGround();
        createEnemy();
    }

    private void setUpGround(){
        ground = new Ground (WorldUtils.createGround(world));
        addActor(ground);
    }

    private void createEnemy() {
        enemy = new Enemy(WorldUtils.createEnemy(world));

     // (1) *****using addListener method
        enemy.addListener(new InputListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                                     int pointer, int button)
            {
                score++;
                yourScoreName = "score: " + score;
                return true;
            }
        });
        /*enemy.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            public void clicked() {
                world.destroyBody(enemy.getBody());
            }});*/
        //bounds = new Rectangle(enemy.getX(), enemy.getY(), enemy.getWidth(),  enemy.getHeight());
        addActor(enemy);

    }

    private void setUpCamera() {
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(VIEWPORT_WIDTH, VIEWPORT_HEIGHT);
        camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2, 0f);
        camera.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta) {
        super.act(delta);
        checkEnemy();

        // Fixed timestep
        accumulator += delta;

        while (accumulator >= delta) {
            world.step(TIME_STEP, 6, 2);
            accumulator -= TIME_STEP;
        }

        //TODO: Implement interpolation

    }

    private void checkEnemy(){
       final Body  body = enemy.getBody();
        UserData userData = enemy.getUserData();

       bounds = new Rectangle(enemy.getBody().getPosition().x, enemy.getBody().getPosition().y, enemy.getUserData().getWidth(),  enemy.getUserData().getHeight());
       // bounds = new Rectangle(body.getPosition().x, body.getPosition().y,userData.getWidth() ,userData.getHeight());

       if (!BodyUtils.enemyInBounds(body,userData)){
           world.destroyBody(body);
             createEnemy();}
    }

    public World getWorld(){
        return world;
    }

 // (2) ****using TouchDown method
      @Override
        public boolean touchDown(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {

            // Need to get the actual coordinates
            translateScreenToWorldCoordinates(x, y);
          //  score++;
           // yourScoreName = "score: " + score;
            if(enemyTouched(touchPoint.x,touchPoint.y)){
              //  world.destroyBody(enemy.getBody());
                score++;
                yourScoreName = "score: " + score;
            }
            return super.touchDown(x, y, pointer, button);
        }
    private boolean enemyTouched(float x, float y) {
        return bounds.contains(x, y);
    }

    private void translateScreenToWorldCoordinates(int x, int y) {
        getCamera().unproject(touchPoint.set(x, y, 0));
    }




    @Override
    public void draw() {
        super.draw();
        batch.begin();
        yourBitmapFontName.setColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        yourBitmapFontName.draw(batch, yourScoreName, 25, 100);
        batch.end();
        enemy.setBounds(enemy.getBody().getPosition().x,enemy.getBody().getPosition().y,enemy.getUserData().getWidth(),enemy.getUserData().getHeight());
        renderer.render(world, camera.combined);
    }
}
```

A screen from my game:

[image]

Comment: You didn't set up the viewport for your Stage (superclass), unless you're doing it externally. The actual Stage doesn't know anything about this secondary camera you've set up in the subclass and are using only for the shape renderer.

Comment: thank you for your response , can you show me how to do that plz , i'm trying to dtecte touch events for actors from William Mora Tutorial , i'm a nwebie  in libgdx , and that's problem stopped me until this day

Comment: Post on the Libgdx forums. Too much to walk through on this site.

Comment: okay , thanks i will try

Answer (score 0):

It should work the way you did it (with the `addListener()` method). But you have to set the correct bounds of the actor (width, height, position): `actor.setBounds(x, y, width, height)`. I would use the body to get these values. You can also use a `ClickListener` instead of the `InputListener`.

Comment: thanks ,        enemy.setBounds(enemy.getBody().getPosition().x, enemy.getBody().getPosition().y, enemy.getUserData().getWidth(),  enemy.getUserData().getHeight());
 i try it but not worked , for bounds X , Y , WIDTH , HEIGHT i initialized them before in EnemyTyp enum not in GameStage Class

Comment: I would use the body you create with the `WorldUtils.createEnemy(world)` method. Make sure the bounds are not 0 (for example with logging, `Gdx.app.log()`).

Comment: u can take a look on my question i set a picture from my game , i try to make enemy in a fixed coordinates to apply the touch event , but the touch event don't detected

Comment: Yes and I think the reason of that is that the actor bounds are not correctly. I had the same issue

Comment: okay , thank you for your effort , i will try to find a solution for them